# Implement specialized entity in ER diagram

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

I'm designing a db and find a situation where im not sure what to do, so first of all lets ilustrate part of the ER diagram with an image:

[image: ER diagram]

As you can see, i have the following:

- A device produces 0:N data's
- The data produced can be of different DataTypes (For example, a
  device can produce temperature data and humidity data at the same
  timestamp)
- A specific data was produced only by 1:1 device
- 1:N relationship between Device and Data. Since data is a
  weak entity (cant exist data without devices), i'll have a composite
  PK in Data formed by ID_DEVICE and TIMESTAMP (not represented in image)
- Since a specific data can only be of 1 type, i have specialized
  "subtypes", from DataType1 to DataType10, and in case of DataType2 i
  have another specialization. Obviously, each of this entities have
  different attributes.

I think the way to go is for each subtype, to inherit the PK from Data entity, since with only TimeStamp + ID_Device cant distinguish if a row is from DataType1 or DataTypeX. That means that the supertype Data entity, doesnt become a table.

In the other hand, if i should create a table for the Data supertype, i can add a field "type" in the specialization relationship in order to uniquely identify each data row.

¿How should i proceed in this case?
Since i think both options are correct, which one offers more benefits and why?
Any improvement or suggestion is allowed! :D

Comment: Which tool are you using to draw the diagram?

Comment: Actually im using pen and paper to make the design. To illustrate my question i used MS Visio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as no one else give an answer and im already doing the implementation, im going to answer my own question with what i finally did.

**I applied the first option i gave, which is to inherit the PK from Data entity (ID_DEVICE, TIMESTAMP) into each of the subtypes. So the supertype Data will not become a table in the db.**

The reason i did that way was because of the type of querys the user is going to do. 95% of the time, the queries will be done to 1 device and to 1 specific datatype, so it doesnt really make sense to have a Data table which include references to the WHOLE amount of rows on each datatype.

In that case, if im asked to show all the values of DATATYPE3 generated by DEVICE 1, i should first query the general DATA table (which contains references to all other DATATYPES even i know i dont need them), and after this, i should query the DATATYPE3 table to actually recover the desired values (since the DATA table dont have values). I think this highly inneficient.

Hope this helps someone! :)

Answer (score 0):

The error with your ERD is, that you only need 1 table for datatype and one for subtype. Then you should have a relation between Data and Aubtype and another relation between subtype and datatype.

The reason is, that the data only belongs to a certain subtype (humidity10, which itself is of type humidity)

Comment: You are telling me that i should have 1 table for DataType and another one for Subtype. I dont know which entity are u refering when say "Subtype" and what fields should have. Also i dont see how can i combine all the DataTypes in only 1 table if each DataType have a different number of fields. Maybe i didnt explained myself good enough, i'll trying again:

A device can produce different types of data, but not all of them, just a subgroup. To simplify, we can have 3 DataTypes (Temp, Humidity and Pressure). Now we can have Device1 producing Temp and Hum and Device2 producing Hum and Pressure.